# Difference between following js code snippets

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and a bit confused about the difference between following code snippets.

Snippet 1:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
};
```

Snippet 2:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
};
```

Can anyone please tell the difference between them?

Comment: The first creates a local variable; the second creates a global variable.

Comment: Perhaps here might be a valuable resource: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 5):

Snippet 1:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
};

var sample = function () {
   var sampleInstance = friendlyChat; //error
   // friendlyChat cannot be accesses here as you have declared it 
   // at function scope which gets destroyed once the function has 
   // returned or completed the execution.
}
```

`friendlyChat` is a local variable and can be accessed only inside this function.

Snippet 2:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
};

var sample = function () {
   var sampleInstance = friendlyChat; 
   // friendlyChat can be accesses here as you have declared it at 
   // windows scope which is available globally.
}
```

`friendlyChat` is a global variable and can be accessed anywhere as it has been declared at root level i.e window.